# Sporandic OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "Servername" returned message "No transaction is active." and Linked Servers

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

**The Configuration**

We have two servers.

- An accounts server called MSSQL-Accounts (SQL 2012 SP1) on premise.
- An Azure cloud server called MSSQL-CRM (SQL 2019).

There is a bidirectional, all port, VPN between the two servers. Each is on a different network, there is no DNS between them. To allow name resolution we have added each to the others hosts and lmhosts files.

Both have DTC enabled and configured as below:

[image]

Both have a remote security context set that is a sys admin role:

[image]

We have tried it with "Enable Promotion of Distributed Transactions for RPC" both on, and off:

[image]

**The Scenario and Error**

MSSQL-CRM will run a stored procedure that will update records on itself and also update some records on the accounts server, MSSQL-Accounts, which will then return a billing ID back to MSSQL-CRM. All the procedures run from MSSQL-CRM, with some inserts and updates to both servers.

***Most of the time this works! And it flew through testing. However, now and again, it fails. This morning it would not work at all. When the procedure was fired, the error it gave was:***

> OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "MSSQL-Accounts"
> returned message "No transaction is active."

On MSSQL-CRM we could still expand our linked server section in SQL Server Management Studio, however, on MSSQL-Accounts server we could not expand the catalogues,

On testing the linked server from MSSQL-Accounts to MSSQL-CRM we got.

[image]

We even went to the lengths of rebooting MSSQL-Accounts, however, the error remained.

We tested the link (right click on the linked server then click "Test Connection"),  from the other end (from MSSQL-CRM to MSSQL-Accounts), and it worked just fine. ***And then magically, at 3pm, it all started working again!***

I can see nothing in the event log, I can see nothing in the SQL logs here (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER2\MSSQL\Log).

Infrastructure confirm the VPN is healthy, and there are no network issues.

Comment: The joys of linked servers, multiplied by the joys of cloud access. In this case you'd expect network connectivity to be the culprit, since that's pretty much what the error is saying. I don't know how it was determined that there "are no network issues"; the ability to transmit packets up and down does not prove that TDS connections in particular work properly. Because there is little to nothing in the way of resilience or recovery for linked server connections, and sometimes broken connections "stick" in the connection pool, you can pretty much expect more of this.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Is there any method to clear down the connection pool when this does fail? What method could be used to monitor the health of TDS connections? I was hoping to avoid an application layer between these servers - the procs worked very gracefully when both databases used to be on the same server.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, no, and SQL Server can be annoyingly persistent at keeping broken connections. A reboot of the originating server does fix that, though (rebooting the target server is normally not necessary), so it sounds like in your case it was a more basic failure of the network layer, since you rebooted the originator and it didn't help. Linked servers work 99% of the time; the troubles start with the remaining 1%. More resilient if also more complicated features that still don't require applications include replication and Service Broker.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Local DTC settings, I have sometimes had to enable three Inbound rules in the Windows Firewall to get everything to work correctly.

[image]